# sqlachemy: Optimizing a query using joins

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am using sqlachemy with MySQL backend. Actually having problems optimizing a query.

I have the following set of models:

```
class Book(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'books'
    name = Column(String(32), primary_key=True)
    sku = Column(Integer, nullable=False)



class Author(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'authors'
    name = Column(String(64), primary_key=True)
    # book
    books = relationship(Book, secondary=Table(
        'author_books', Base.metadata,
        Column('author', String(32),
               ForeignKey(Author.name), primary_key=True),
        Column('book', String(64), ForeignKey("book.title"),
               primary_key=True)
    ), backref=backref('book_authors', cascade="save-update"))
```

And was doing a query:

```
authors_with_books = [(autor.name, [book.name for book in books]) for author in session.query(Authors)]
```

Which is actually very very slow :(

Answer (score 0):

Your query is slow because you are joining data on python.

Do it on database.

try something like that:

```
authors_with_books = session.query(Author.name, Book.name)
```

It'll create a join on SQL

Comment: I am not sure about this. E.g. Author & Book are related with M2M relation. Actually I was trying to do `session.query(Author).join(Author.books)` but it did not help

Answer (score 0):

authors_with_books = session.query(Author).join(Author.books)

or

Use 'lazyload' param.

Try rewrite many_to_many table in models. It's work for me:

```
class Author(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'authors'
    name = Column(String(64), primary_key=True)
    books = relationship('Book', secondary='author_books')


author_book = Table(
    'author_books', Base.metadata,
    Column('author', String(32), ForeignKey("author.name", match=u'FULL'), primary_key=True),
    Column('book', String(64), ForeignKey("book.title", match=u'FULL'), primary_key=True)
)
```

And I think ForeignKey(Author.name) - Incorrect code, fix it.

Comment: Your answer would be a lot more helpful (and more likely to attract upvotes) if you explain your approach and describe why it works.